# socket exception socket not connected android

Tags: android

Hello 
In my android application i am trying to run a application using GPRS connection and not WIFI.
When tried to run in wifi the app runs fine.
The browser works fine with the APN settings set but when trying to connect to server using my application it gives me socket exception.

I am using the below permissions in manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses- permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name= "android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name= "android.permission.WRITE_APN_SETTINGS" ></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" ></uses-permission>
```

I am receiving Socket not connected exception.
Is there any other permission which i need to add for using GPRS connection other than WIFI.

Log details

> 10-27 18:26:19.689: WARN/CalSyncSvc(166): com.motorola.blur.service.email.protocol.activesync.ASException: Problem executing HTTP POST
>   10-27 18:26:19.689: WARN/CalSyncSvc(166):     at com.motorola.blur.service.email.protocol.activesync.ActiveSyncMgr.sendRequest(Unknown Source)
>   10-27 18:26:19.689: WARN/CalSyncSvc(166):     at com.motorola.blur.service.email.protocol.activesync.ActiveSyncMgr.sendXMLCommandNoProvisoning(Unknown Source)
>   10-27 18:26:19.689: WARN/CalSyncSvc(166):     at com.motorola.blur.service.email.protocol.activesync.ActiveSyncMgr.sendXMLCommand0(Unknown Source)
>   10-27 18:26:19.689: WARN/CalSyncSvc(166):     at com.motorola.blur.service.email.protocol.activesync.ActiveSyncMgr.sendXMLCommand(Unknown Source)
>   10-27 18:26:19.689: WARN/CalSyncSvc(166):     at com.motorola.blur.service.email.protocol.activesync.ActiveSyncMgr.sendFolderSyncCommand(Unknown Source)
>   10-27 18:26:19.689: WARN/CalSyncSvc(166):     at com.motorola.blur.service.email.protocol.activesync.ProviderAPI.sendFolderSync(Unknown Source)
>   10-27 18:26:19.689: WARN/CalSyncSvc(166):     at com.motorola.blur.service.email.protocol.activesync.ProviderAPI.updateMapFromFolderSync(Unknown Source)
>   10-27 18:26:19.689: WARN/CalSyncSvc(166):     at com.motorola.blur.service.email.protocol.activesync.ProviderAPI.updateFromFolderSync(Unknown Source)
>   10-27 18:26:19.689: WARN/CalSyncSvc(166):     at com.motorola.blur.calendar.sync.activesync.SyncService.syncAccount(Unknown Source)
>   10-27 18:26:19.689: WARN/CalSyncSvc(166):     at com.motorola.blur.calendar.sync.activesync.SyncService$QueueEntry.run(Unknown Source)
>   10-27 18:26:19.689: WARN/CalSyncSvc(166):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:416)
>   10-27 18:26:19.689: WARN/CalSyncSvc(166):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:256)
>   10-27 18:26:19.689: WARN/CalSyncSvc(166):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:122)
>   10-27 18:26:19.689: WARN/CalSyncSvc(166):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:648)
>   10-27 18:26:19.689: WARN/CalSyncSvc(166):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:673)
>   10-27 18:26:19.689: WARN/CalSyncSvc(166):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1058)
>   10-27 18:26:19.689: WARN/CalSyncSvc(166):     at com.motorola.blur.util.concurrent.BlurThreadFactory$BlurPooledThread.run(Unknown Source)
>   10-27 18:26:19.689: WARN/CalSyncSvc(166): Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Socket is not connected
>   10-27 18:26:19.689: WARN/CalSyncSvc(166):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.connectStreamWithTimeoutSocketImpl(Native Method)
>   10-27 18:26:19.689: WARN/CalSyncSvc(166):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.connectStreamWithTimeoutSocket(OSNetworkSystem.java:140)
>   10-27 18:26:19.689: WARN/CalSyncSvc(166):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:229)
>   10-27 18:26:19.689: WARN/CalSyncSvc(166):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:521)
>   10-27 18:26:19.689: WARN/CalSyncSvc(166):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:1019)
>   10-27 18:26:19.689: WARN/CalSyncSvc(166):     at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:317)
>   10-27 18:26:19.689: WARN/CalSyncSvc(166):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:129)
>   10-27 18:26:19.689: WARN/CalSyncSvc(166):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
>   10-27 18:26:19.689: WARN/CalSyncSvc(166):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
>   10-27 18:26:19.689: WARN/CalSyncSvc(166):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:348)
>   10-27 18:26:19.689: WARN/CalSyncSvc(166):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
>   10-27 18:26:19.689: WARN/CalSyncSvc(166):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
>   10-27 18:26:19.689: WARN/CalSyncSvc(166):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
>   10-27 18:26:19.689: WARN/CalSyncSvc(166):     ... 17 more
>   Please let me know your valuable suggestions.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: add the stacktrace to you question

Comment: Have edited the question with logs.

Answer (score 0):

After my long search in this have come to know that Android applications does not run fine on WAP client but runs fine using GPRS internet connection.

This means that if you have only WAP access point set in your Mobile Networks settings, you can use browser to some extend, but not take direct socket connections. You need to a) have Internet access point set in "Wireless and network" / "Mobile Networks" and have it selected as default for android applications to get unrestricted access.